# How to add latex reference to code block of pandoc markdown file?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I've read the guide http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#verbatim-code-blocks

In the example

```
~~~~ {#mycode .haskell .numberLines startFrom="100"}
qsort []     = []
qsort (x:xs) = qsort (filter (< x) xs) ++ [x] ++
               qsort (filter (>= x) xs)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I add a latex label `\label{code}` to this block of code so I can reference it by `\ref{code}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the page you link to the `#mycode` bit is the identifier for the code block, this is equivalent to LaTeX's `\label`. You can reference this code block using an [internal link](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#internal-links) and the identifier `#mycode`.